# Getting the rows cell to line up with parameters in a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I am using a datagridview on a win app designed in c#2010 express.
 In the _row leave event of my datagrid I would like to use the
TableAdapter.usp_insert() that I created. But how does one match up the data in the cells of the datagridview row to the parameters in the stored procedure.

This is what if found so far!

```
Int i;
i = datagridview1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
...
....
// Eventually 
string id = dataGridView1.Rows[i].cell[0].Value.ToString();
@para1 = id;
```

Etc..

What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I solved my problem

`Int i;` 
`i = datagridview1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;` ... .... 

 
Eventually assign the the specific column/row to the declared value:
`string id = dataGridView1.Rows[i].cell[0].Value.ToString();` 
 `@para1 = id;` 
Etc..

is that answer I needed